# Opening full screen programs on a 2nd screen

Tags: multiple-monitors

How can I get full screen programs like games to open on on my secondary screen?

I have tried programs like ultramon and swapscreen but instead of switching the games to the secondary screen they appear on both and crash the game.

Comment: For which operating system? Mac, Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the game - most (modern) games use Direct X and will always render on the primary monitor.

Without any special drivers such as ATI Eyefinity (Forget the Nvidia version), by far the easiest thing you can do is go in to settings and simply change the primary and secondary monitor around (Just right click on secondary monitor and tick the primary button).

If you don't have any other reason for the other one being primary, this should do what you want without problems.